Proof of concurrency of angle bisectors w.r.t. side $BC$.
Question:
Let the altitudes $BD$ & $CE$ of an acute $∆ABC$ meet at $H$. Suppose that the circumcircle of $∆ADE$ cuts the circumcircle of $∆ABC$ at $A$ & $F$. Prove that the angle bisectors of $\angle BHC$ & $\angle BFC$ concur at a point $G$ on $BC$.
So far:
Construct $HG$ and extend $FG$ to meet the circumcircle of $∆ABC$ again at $F'$. $O$ & $P$ are the circumcenters of $∆ABC$ and $∆ADE$, respectively.

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be the three corresponding angles of the vertices of $∆ABC$. Since $ADHE$ is concyclic ($\angle AEH + \angle ADH = 180^\circ$), $\angle BHC = \angle DHE = 180 - \alpha$. So, $\angle BHG = 90 - \frac{\alpha}{2}$.
Then, by inscribed angle theorem, $\angle BFC = \alpha$.
This is where I got stuck from. If I can show that $\angle BAF' = \frac{\alpha}{2}$, then I'll be done. Also, I observe that $HG \parallel AF'$, though I can't prove this either. In my opinion, proving that $HG \parallel AF'$ is what needs to be done to complete the problem.
Any help would be appreciated...

Note: Only key steps will be provided.
First let's state a lemma:

In the figure, $AD$ is the angle bisector of $\angle BAC$ iff $$\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{BD}{DC}$$
Next the question:

Let $FF'$ be the angle bisector of $\angle BFC$, we are going to show that $HG$ bisects $\angle BHC$ by showing that $$\frac{BG}{GC}=\frac{HB}{HC}.$$
Key steps:
$(1)$  Because $FF'$ bisects $\angle BFC$, we have
$$\frac{BG}{GC}=\frac{FB}{FC} ----- (*)$$
$(2)$ Show that $\angle BFE = \angle CFD$, then $\Delta BFE \sim \Delta CFD$. Hence
$$\frac{FB}{FC}=\frac{BE}{CD} ----- (**)$$
$(3)$ Show that $\Delta BEH \sim \Delta CDH$ and hence
$$\frac{BE}{CD}=\frac{HB}{HC} ----- (***)$$
From $(*), (**), (***)$, we conclude that
$$\frac{BG}{GC}=\frac{HB}{HC}.$$
Hence $HG$ bisects $\angle BHC$ by our lemma.


In picture F' is where the diameter of circumcircle O(which is the perpendicular bisector of BC) meets the bisector of angle BFC. Also I is the point where the perpendicular bisector of BC meets the bisector of the angle BHC. That is F' is mid point of arc BC and $BAF'=\frac {\alpha}2$ and you are done.

How do you show that $OF'$ is the perpendicular bisector of $BC$?

@JoyneelBepari, This is a well known theorem. FF' is the bisector of BFC so it meet the mid point of arc BC at F'. The radius connecting O to F' is perpendicular  on the chord BC and bisects it.

May I know the name of this theorem or where I can study about it?

@JoyneelBepari, See(https://www.cuemath.com/ncert-solutions/in-any-triangle-abc-if-the-angle-bisector-of-a-and-perpendicular-bisector-of-bc-intersect-prove-that-they-intersect-on-the-circumcircle-of-the-triangle-abc/)

Okay, got it! But even still, this "proof" has loopholes in my opinion — it has circular reasoning. In my working, $GH$ is the angle bisector of $\angle BHC$ and $FG$ has been extended to $FF'$, and we have to show that $OF' \perp BC$. Directly claiming that $OF' \perp BC$ constitutes circular reasoning.
Only if we can show that $OF' \perp BC$, then we get that $FF'$ is the angle bisector of $\angle BFC$.

Then again, our task is to prove that $FF'$ is the angle bisector. Stating that $FF'$ is angle bisector, which implies that $F'$ is the midpoint of arc $BC$ is circular and frail reasoning.

@JoyneelBepari, You need to consider two facts: First the line connecting the centers of two intersecting circles is perpendicular on their common chord. Second is that the circle passin through two vertexes anf the orthocenter is equal to circumcircle of the triangle.That is quadrilateral BOCN is a square and it's diagonals are perpendicular on each other.
